# How can I format to show text inside "<" and ">"?

Tags: support, markdown

I've posted a lot to StackOverflow, and I've noticed something kind of irritating with the formatting in writing questions and comments. If I need to put something inside a < and a >, without spaces in the middle (like right there), it will think it's code and not show up, like this

(obviously it won't come up what I wrote there, or else this wouldn't be an issue, but if you open up the question to edit you can see what's written there.)

If I want it to show up, right now I have to add an extra set of brackets inside of the originals with a junk variable, like right <here> (again, open in edit window to see).

This is really annoying when trying to show variables like lists that require those brackets, and I feel like the junk variables could confuse people looking at the edits. Is there a way to get around this formatting? Thanks!

Comment: Just wrap in backticks.

Comment: Isn't this the wrong dupe?

Comment: @rene I dunno, I remember this specific question being asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Put backticks around `<html>tags</html>`.
```

becomes:

Put backticks around `<html>tags</html>`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple, but couldn't for the life of me figure out what haha

Answer (score 18):

You can use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to get them <displayed without being marked a code> if they in fact aren't code.

Comment: Supplemental to Martijn Pieters answer, for those who will find this question by title but are not interested in code blocks.

Answer (score 4):

Use backticks (`) to show code in a post.

If the text **is** code then it should be put in `code blocks`